# Sharepoint Tracing Service lost trace events

Tags: sharepoint

I have a problem of a Sharepoint Server that regularly stops logging, instead the logfiles (in 12\LOGS) only contain

> 05/05/2009 14:17:09.12    wsstracing.exe (0x0B24)                     0x0254  ULS Logging                     Unified Logging Service         uls1    Monitorable Tracing Service lost trace events.  Current value 11.

(Current value fluctuates a lot)

Any ideas how that can be troubleshooted? Restarting the service or server fixes, but only for a few days, and I don't know what could be the cause of this?

Comment: We have the same problem. The tracing service also would't stop sometimes, so a reboot is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug open for this issue:

https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=408671&SiteID=428

No fix available yet I'm afraid other than restarting the services.

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Comment: hmm, after I enter my Windows Live ID - it works fine here...

Answer (score 1):

It's usually due to low memory conditions on the server. However it can sometimes just happen...

Comment: The logging stops _completely_ when you have less than 200MB of free space on C: regardless of where you've set up the log to be written. But it writes a notification to the application events about that.